# how to autofill data on iframe by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

Hello I want to autofill data in iframe on cross domain.I have a code but it's not working. please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
function autoFill() {
var f=fm.document.forms[0];
f.form-control.value='Zanne';
f.submit();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="autoFill();">autoFill</button>
</div>
<iframe name="fm" id="fm" src="url.com" width="100&#37;" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

the input filled:

Have any way to do this.

Comment: nope.. not unless the document in the iframe is on the same domain. google cross origin scripting.

Comment: haven't any way ?

Comment: what's your "legitimate" user case here?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a CORS violation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

There are some workarounds to this. You have to use the postMessage API. Your parent window would need to send JavaScript events to the iFrame, which would need to have an event listener and react to it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: No it's not a CORS issue. Accessing iFrame is a whole different security concern

Comment: If its on the same domain, protocol, port, then you are right.

Then you would do something like document.frames[0].forms[0]

Comment: You can't use CORS to allow iFrame access cross domain. It is for cross domain requests which is different